# Pandas rename columns according to my dict

Tags: python, pandas, table-rename

I have many dataframes in pickle format, they have the same information, but columns name are not identical in all of them.
For example:

```
>     file name:    Columns_['Weryfikacja UK - 2022-04-14.xlsx_20uk-woocommerce-last-5yrs-expo.pkl'].pkl
>     columns_nam:  Index(['domain', 'phones', 'phones_data_source', 'company_name', 'SourceFile'], dtype='object')
> 
>     file name:    Columns_['US _ Canada - rechurn - 01.2022-04.2022.xlsx_Other.pkl'].pkl
>     columns_nam:  Index(['Phone', 'Domain', 'SourceFile'], dtype='object')
> 
>     file name:    Columns_['2022-08 - US _ Canada.xlsx_29.08-02.09 WixStore USCA.pkl'].pkl
>     columns_nam:  Index(['Phone', 'Alternative phone 1', 'Alternative phone2', 'Alternative phone3', 'Alternative phone4', 'SourceFile'], dtype='object')
```

I have a dict like this to rename columns names in all files:

```
my_dict = {
"Domain": ['Domain','domain', 'WWW', 'www'],
"Phone": ['Phone','phone_number', 'phones', 'Tel'],
"AlternativePhone1": ['Alternative phone1','Alternative phone 2', 'phones2'],
"AlternativePhone2": ['Alternative phone2','Alternative phone 3', 'phones3'],
"AlternativePhone3": ['Alternative phone3','Alternative phone 4', 'phones4'],
"AlternativePhone4": ['Alternative phone4','Alternative phone 5', 'phones5'],
"SourceFile": ['SourceFile']
}
```

I need a help with code, how should I do it?

```
for file in glob.glob("*.pkl"):
    df = pd.read_pickle(file)
```

On output I would like to have something like this

```
>     file name:    Columns_['2022-08 - US _ Canada.xlsx_29.08-02.09 WixStore USCA.pkl'].pkl
>     columns_nam:  Index(['Phone', 'AlternativePhone1', 'AlternativePhone2', 'AlternativePhone3', 'AlternativePhone4', 'SourceFile'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: It would depend on the current data, and the desired output, but when using `pandas.read_pickle` one can pass the columns. Something like this should do the work for the first dataframe: `df_uk = pd.read_pickle('Columns_["Weryfikacja UK - 2022-04-14.xlsx_20uk-woocommerce-last-5yrs-expo.pkl"].pkl', columns=my_dict.keys())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The easiest way

I don't think there is a standard way to rename columns based on a list of possible names built-in to pandas, but its easy enough with a few for loops:

```py
my_dict = {
    "Domain": ['Domain','domain', 'WWW', 'www'],
    "Phone": ['Phone','phone_number', 'phones', 'Tel'],
}

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "WWW": [1,2,3,4,5], 
    "phones": [1,2,3,4,5]
})

for (goal, names) in my_dict.items():
    for name in names:
        if name in df.columns:
            df.rename(columns={name:goal}, inplace=True)
```

## A cleaner way

The `pandas.rename` function does not actually care if the dataframe contains all the columns you provide new names for in the `columns` dictonary. This means that if we convert `my_dict` from `newname -> List[oldname]` to the `oldname -> newname` fromat expected by `columns` we can rename the columns without any for loops.

```py
columns_dict = dict(sum([[(old, new) for old in olds] for (new, olds) in my_dict.items()], []))

# columns_dict = {
#     'Domain': 'Domain', 'domain': 'Domain', 'WWW': 'Domain', 'www': 'Domain', 
#     'Phone': 'Phone', 'phone_number': 'Phone', 'phones': 'Phone', 'Tel': 'Phone'
# }

df.rename(columns=columns_dict, inplace=True)
```